# Browser displays TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

First i do like to apologize if it's a noob mistake.  I'm trying to do a login page but i keep encountering this error. How can i fix this?
Thank you all!

[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rc2R.png)
[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csbr0.png)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import logo from '../assets/logo.png';

function initialState() {
  return { user: '', password: '' };
}


const LoginPage = () => { 

  const [values, setValues] = useState();

  function onChange(event) {`enter code here`
    const { value, name } = event.target;

    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  return (
    <LoginCard>
      <LoginLogoWrapper>
        <img src={ logo } alt="logo"/>
      </LoginLogoWrapper>
      <Form>
        <p>Acesse sua conta</p>
        <input type="email" name="user" placeholder="E-mail" onChange={onChange} value={values.user}/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Senha" onChange={onChange} value={values.password}/>
        <button>Entrar</button>
      </Form>
    </LoginCard>
  );
};


export default LoginPage;
```

As requested i have put the code in the question, i'm sorry i'm new to stack overflow and coding in general.
I already tried putting the function initializing the values inside the constant but it just throws another error.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample piece of code and attempts you made for this problem so that we can work together better? Seems like **user** property's not initialized as it should

Comment: Hi @AjeetShah i just put the code as requested. Thank you both for answering.

Comment: It looks like you need to initialize your state with your initial state like so. `const [ values, setValues] = useState(initialState());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I saw at first from your screenshot, that the useState({...}) don't have appropriate properties. Try like this:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    user: "",
    password: ""
})
```

For more details check out [this article](https://medium.com/technoetics/create-basic-login-forms-using-react-js-hooks-and-bootstrap-2ae36c15e551).

Comment: Hi! This solved the problem, could you please go into a little depth of why using useState as empty doesn't work? I'm new to react and trying to learn. Thank you for answering !

Comment: @EstevãoUrbano `useState();` accepts an argument, which is the value to use as the initial state. Without that argument, the state is initially set to `undefined`. This means that later on when you do `values.user`, `values` is `undefined` and you get the crash. By providing an initial state value you can always use `values.user` because `values` always exists.

Comment: When first time your component function is run, the "setValues" function captures the initial value. For 2-nd time it's run, you then make a copy of that "setValues", but that's the function, that captured the initial value of "values" and never updates

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your useState hook. You are not passing any initial State to it as a prameter. That is why the `values.user` is undefined.

Read This properly https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

```
function initialState() {
  return { user: '', password: '' };
}


const LoginPage = () => { 

  const [values, setValues] = useState();  // pass initial state to your useState

Recommended --->>> const [values, setValues] = useState({user: '', password: ''});

  function onChange(event) {`enter code here`
    const { value, name } = event.target;


// Change it like this for more readable and logically appropriate writing
    setValues(prevState => {  //pass previous state first
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Ritik for your answer, i surely will take a look at that.